# Removing Link from Instagram image feed

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm using some JavaScript to pull in my Instagram feed but I want to remove the link of each image that takes them to the page on Instagram. I've tried a few attempts but ended up breaking it, anyone got any ideas of what I should be removing?

```
 embedImage = function(photo) {
var a, img;
img = $('<img/>').attr({
  //'src': photo.images.thumbnail.url,
  //'width': photo.images.thumbnail.width,
  //'height': photo.images.thumbnail.height
  'src': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'width': photo.images.standard_resolution.width,
  'height': photo.images.standard_resolution.height
});
a = $('<a />').attr({
  'href': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'target': '_blank',
  'class': 'pull-left'
}).append(img).appendTo(tag_name);
 };

onPhotoLoaded = function(data) {
var photo, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
if (data.meta.code === 200 && data.data) {
  _ref = data.data;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    photo = _ref[_i];
    _results.push(embedImage(photo));
  }
  return _results;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the attributes on the `a` tag that is created except for the class.